# Read kuberbetes pod stdout from node.js

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, stdout

Does someone have a way or a library that can show how to (if possible) reading stdout and stderr from containers in Kubernetes pods?

The code will be running in a container/pod next to the source pods that it will read from.

Answer (score 2):

You would generally use the `pods/log` subresource. The official JS client does provide a high-level wrapper for this in [the library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/src/log.ts) but I don't see any specific examples of usage.